# How to properly solve macro conflict (GetMessage) between Windows API and DirectX API & other APIs developed by microsoft

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, directx

**Problem:**

I'm developing a desktop D3D12 application, so naturally, I need `<Windows.h>` and `<WinUser.h>` it included to be able to create a window, but there's a GetMessage macro that conflicts with `IDXGIInfoQueue::GetMessage` and `ID3D12InfoQueue::GetMessage` (and also `ID3D11InfoQueue::GetMessage` `ID3D10InfoQueue::GetMessage`)

other discussions about this macro I found on StackOverflow and Github are all saying that one should change their `GetMessage` function name to something else, but clearly, since I didn't develop DirectX API, I have no control over this...

**I include both Windows API and DirectX API headers together in a precompiled header file**

**Imperfect/Failed solutions I tried so far:**

1. I could just ignore the issue or write `#undef GetMessage` before I call these methods, then their names will become `IDXGIInfoQueue::GetMessageW`, `ID3D12InfoQueue::GetMessageW`, `ID3D11InfoQueue::GetMessageW` ...

```
// RenderPipeline.cpp
CComPtr<IDXGIInfoQueue> DXGIInfoQueue;
CComPtr<ID3D12InfoQueue> D3D12InfoQueue;
...
#undef GetMessage
SIZE_T Size = 0;
//HRESULT result = DXGIInfoQueue->GetMessage(0, nullptr, &Size);  // compile error
HRESULT result = DXGIInfoQueue->GetMessageW(0, nullptr, &Size);  // compile success, runs ok
//HRESULT result = D3D12InfoQueue->GetMessage(0, nullptr, &Size);  // compile error
HRESULT result = D3D12InfoQueue->GetMessageW(0, nullptr, &Size);  // compile success, runs ok
...
```

*I'm a little surprised at first that even though the names were wrong, it compiled successfully and these methods can still be called normally runtime (under the name `GetMessageW`), then I figured that the reason why this works is that the corresponding original methods still take the same arguments and their addresses are still in the same index position in the virtual method table of their interfaces, it's their index in the virtual method table instead of their names that are relevant here, so the code runs normally here. But still, it just feels wrong using the wrong names...*

2. if I write `#undef GetMessage` before I include DirectX headers, the code which I actually call `GetMessage` to retrieve messages from the window message queue will be wrong, surely I could just change that from `GetMessage(&Msg...)` to `GetMessageW(&Msg...)` **but I'm a little used to using these macros now**...

```
// pch.h
...
#include <Windows.h>
#undef GetMessage
...

// Run.cpp
...
MSG Msg;
//while (GetMessage(&Msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {  // compile error, but I want this to work because it looks nicer
while (GetMessageW(&Msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {  // compile success
    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
}
...
```

3. I tried adding `#define NOUSER` in the precompiled header file before `#include <Windows.h>` (and `#undef NOUSER` later) and then add `#include <WinUser.h>` again in the `Run.cpp` where I handle window messages, but that didn't work, the macros didn't come back because there are `#ifndef _WINUSER_` `#define _WINUSER_` definitions in the `<WinUser.h>` file which prevents that file from being included multiple times...

```
// pch.h
...
#define NOUSER
#include <Windows.h>
#undef NOUSER
...

// Run.cpp
...
#include <WinUser.h>  // doesn't work...
MSG Msg;
//while (GetMessage(&Msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {  // compile error
while (GetMessageW(&Msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {  // compile success
    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
//  DispatchMessage(&Msg);  // compile error
    DispatchMessageW(&Msg);  // compile success
}
...
```

**Sidenote:**

`GetMessage` isn't the only macro that creates name conflict, I remember there's a `GetObject` macro that can conflict with a method with the same name in the Media Foundation API (this API is also developed by Microsoft, of course)... I'm a little annoyed that Microsoft didn't consider solving these macro conflicts all these years...

**Edit:**
Thanks everyone for comments/answers, in the end I took Remy Lebeau's advice and put my DirectX code into a separate project in the solution (and added `#define NOUSER` in its pch header) and it worked as intended

Comment: #1 is usually what happens. It doesn't really cause any problems.

Comment: The best solution is to NOT mix conflicting Win32 and DirectX functionalities in the same translation unit to begin with. Isolate them from each other. Wrap your DirectX logic into a different unit that doesn't use Win32, and then call it from your Win32 code as needed. Or vice versa.  I know, easier said then done, though...

Comment: @RemyLebeau - but *IDXGIInfoQueue* declared in *dxgidebug.h* which at begin include *windows.h*. so nothing to isolate here

Comment: *DXGIInfoQueue->GetMessageW* is ok. no problem here. nothing need todo. no any conflict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nothing need do here and no any conflict or problems in your code. you already viewed this yourself

> it compiled successfully and these methods can still be called
> normally runtime

and you correct - methods called not by name but by address in virtual table. the *winuser.h* always included before *IDXGIInfoQueue* declaration, so already inside interface declaration `GetMessage` expanded to `GetMessageW` or `GetMessageA`. the same in your code, which call method on interface ( `DXGIInfoQueue->GetMessage`). as result names coincide.

> But still, it just feels wrong using the wrong names...

here you have wrong feels. again - all is ok and nothing need todo

Answer (score 1):

Recently I found a solution that appears more elegant to me; I can just do this while including DirectX headers:

```
#pragma push_macro("GetMessage")
#undef GetMessage // temporarily disable GetMessage macro
#include <DXGI.h> // now GetMessage won't be named GetMessageW anymore
#include <D3D11.h>
// and possibly some other headers...
#pragma pop_macro("GetMessage") // now GetMessage macro returns to normal
```